# How to fill a Jquery multicolumn selectbox from code behind ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to use something like [jquerymulticolumn](http://code.google.com/p/jquerymulticolumnselectbox/).
But i can't use it from code behind. How can i do it or anyone suggest me another multicolumn selectbox ?

aspx:

```
.
.
<td>

   <div id="datatable">
       <table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <tr>
             <th>ID</th><th>Action Name</th><th>Action ID</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <asp:repeater id="rep" runat="server">
               <itemtemplate>
                  <tr>
                     <td><%#Eval("AKSIYON_ID")%></td><td><%#Eval("AKSIYON_ADI")%></td><td><%#Eval("AKSIYON_ID")%></td>
                   </tr>
               </itemtemplate>
             </asp:repeater>
          </table>
      </div>

   </td>
   .
   . 
     <script type="text/javascript">

      $("#datatable").multicolselect({
          buttonImage: "../Images/selectbutton.gif",
          valueCol: 1,
          hideCol: 0
      });

      </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jquerymulticolumn` is using a HTML table to populate its drop down. You could dynamically populate this table using an [ASP.NET Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx):

```
<div id="datatable">
<table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>ID</th><th>Key</th><th>Fruit</th>
</tr>
  <asp:repeater id="rep" runat="server">
    <itemtemplate>
      <tr>
         <td><%#eval("ID") %></td><td><%#eval("Key") %></td><td><%#eval("FruitName") %></td>
      </tr>
    </itemtemplate>
  </asp:repeater>
</table>
</div>
```

Then in your code-behind, you can bind the Repeater to a datasource.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) LoadData();    
}

public void LoadData()
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM orders",    
        "server=(local);database=northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    rep.DataSource = table;
    rep.DataBind();
}
```

*Code snippet taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx)*

Comment: You need to bind the data to `rep`, the Repeater control. Not `datatable`, the div.

Comment: Thx i solve this problem.But when i press the "down" image button postback is working... how can do postback false ?

Comment: @Serdar Please post some of your code into your question (by editing) so that we can see

Comment: i added my aspx code.its simple.i use a masterpage and updatepanel.

Comment: How to fire on combobox selectedchange event ??

Comment: @Serdar Your question was related to populating the `combobox` with data from the database. I believe I've helped you with this. If you are now having issues with the functionality of the combobox I would recommend asking a new question regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You ca do something similar with the `List Box` control which have the property called `MultiColumn`.

Have a look at this documents about [ListBox.MultiColumn Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn.aspx) and [Specify the Column in a Multi-Column List Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176505%28v=office.12%29.aspx)